# Why does `git checkout <branch> <file>` stage the change?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-checkout

If I start from a clean working tree and run `git checkout <branch> <file>`, where `<branch>` has a different version of this file, I end up with a staged rather than an unstaged change.

What's the reason for this? Is this just for consistency with other commands like `git mv`, which you would expect to stage changes? Is it for convenience when using `git checkout` to resolve merge conflicts? Or is there some other rationale?

It seems mildly odd to me since just using `git checkout <branch> <file>` does not offer any indication of whether I plan to commit the change.

Comment: In `git checkout <branch> <file>`, the branch is resolved as a tree, the tree of the head commit of the branch. The command updates the index first for the given file and then update the file in the working tree to match the version in the index. So now the file in the working tree and in the index are updated to be the same. It's just as staged as it is by `git add <file>`. `git checkout --help` for more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does checkout sometimes stage a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837246/why-does-checkout-sometimes-stage-a-file)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's really an implementation detail that the Git authors chose to let show through.

Git cannot—or rather, at one point, *could* not—read files directly from the repository into the work-tree.  It has (or had) to pass them through an intermediary first: it had to copy them, or at least their vital statistics,<sup>1</sup> somewhere else.  Only then could Git copy the data to a work-tree file.<sup>2</sup>  The "somewhere else" is an *index* entry.  The index is also called the staging area.

When you `git checkout` an entire commit, this is what you want anyway.  So the internal limitation, of copying to the index first and only then to the work-tree, was actually a plus.  So this mechanism, of copying into the index first, and only then on into the work-tree, was embedded into the implementation.  Then, eventually, the user-oriented `git checkout` front end gained the ability to check out one individual file, or some small subset of files ... and it continued to do so *through* the index.  The implementation detail became a documented feature.

Note that sometimes, the index is in use as a helper area during a conflicted merge.  In this case, for some file *F*, there are up to *three* entries, in numbered slots 1 (base), 2 (`--ours`), and 3 (`--theirs`), instead of just one entry in the normal slot-zero.  When this is so, you can extract any of the three index slot entries to the work-tree without disturbing the index.  But if you use `git checkout` to extract a file from some other commit-or-tree, Git copies the file into the index, writing it to slot zero.  This has the side effect of *removing* the higher-numbered slots, resolving the merge conflict!

---

<sup>1</sup>The main one is the hash ID.  As [ElpieKay noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163307/why-does-git-checkout-branch-file-stage-the-change#comment75345524_44163307), Git has to resolve the commit hash to a tree hash, then search the various trees to find whichever file(s) is/are of interest, so that it can obtain the blob hash.  The index entry itself has a bunch more data as well, though, including `stat` structure data for the work-tree file, to make Git go fast.

<sup>2</sup>You can still use this work-flow, by using `git read-tree` to copy a tree into the index, then using `git checkout-index` to copy the index to the work-tree.  Originally, Git consisted of a bunch of shell scripts like `git-checkout` wrapped around some fundamental C-coded pieces like `git-read-tree`.  (The names were all hyphenated like this and there was no front end `git` command.)

Answer (score 4):

### The Short Answer

1. `git checkout` **always** copies items out of the index into the worktree.
2. If you specify a commit other than the one you're on (e.g. the HEAD of another branch), checkout **will always first** copy the items from that commit into the index.
3. Anything in the index that differs from HEAD will show as a "staged change". This is by definition.

See also [Git checkout file from branch without changing index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50158417/8910547)