# What does it mean to have a remote repository and a remote branch as arguments to checkout?

Tags: git

I saw a git command from [unable to create file ... Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561400/unable-to-create-file-permission-denied/)

```
git checkout origin develop
```

I only know check out a local branch. What does it mean to have a remote repository and a remote branch as arguments to checkout? I can't find it in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Comment: I think you are able to checkout a branch to your local repository that tracks a remote branch. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `git checkout origin develop` means "check out file (**file**, not branch!) named `develop` from the branch (**branch**, not remote!) named `origin`". If you have branch `origin` and the branch points to a commit containing file `develop` the command succeeds.

But you probably have neither one so the command actually doesn't make sense. StackOverflow is full of bad questions and incorrect answers; don't believe everything you see.

A meaningful command here could be `git checkout origin/develop` which means "check out commit pointed to by the remote tracking reference named `origin/develop`".

Another meaningful command here could be `git checkout develop` which means "create a new local branch named `develop` branching it from the remote tracking reference named `origin/develop`; setup tracking so that the remote tracking reference named `origin/develop` becomes the upstream branch for the local branch named `develop`".

See the `git checkout` docs at https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

You *don't* have both a repository and a branch here.  Instead, you have a *tree-ish* and a *pathspec*.  The *tree-ish* is a commit specifier, `origin`, which is short for `origin/HEAD`, which is short for ... well, see below.  The *pathspec* is `develop` which just means *the file named `develop`*.  If there is no such file, this command will simply fail.

#### Long: how to read Git documentation

The [syntax for `git checkout` is](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_synopsis):

1. `git checkout [-q] [-f] [-m] [<branch>]`
2. `git checkout [-q] [-f] [-m] --detach [<branch>]`
3. `git checkout [-q] [-f] [-m] [--detach] <commit>`
4. `git checkout [-q] [-f] [-m] [[-b|-B|--orphan] <new_branch>] [<start_point>]`
5. `git checkout [-f|--ours|--theirs|-m|--conflict=<style>] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>...`
6. `git checkout [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>...`
7. `git checkout (-p|--patch) [<tree-ish>] [--] [<paths>...]`

None of these allow you to specify a branch name *twice*.

Try matching:

```
git checkout origin develop
```

to the above seven possible syntax lines.  It doesn't match #1, which allows only one `<branch>` argument and no additional arguments.  It doesn't match #2, which requires a literal `--detach`.  It doesn't match #3, which allows only one `<commit>` argument and no daditional arguments.  It doesn't match #4, which allows only one optional `<start-point>` argument, and it doesn't match #7, which requires a literal `-p` or `--patch`.

It *does* match #5 and #6.  These probably shouldn't be two separate syntax lines, and in the subsequent [description section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_description), they aren't—it's just one section with:

```
git checkout [<tree-ish>] -- [<pathspec> ...]
```

which has the flaw that it fails to mention all the optional flags in the shortened summary, but it then mentions those flags in the body of the text:

> Overwrite paths in the working tree by replacing with the contents
>    in the index or in the <tree-ish> (most often a commit). When a
>    <tree-ish> is given, the paths that match the <pathspec> are
>    updated both in the index and in the working tree.
>
> The index may contain unmerged entries because of a previous failed
>    merge. By default ...
>    [snip - this is where flags like `-f` and `--ours` and so on get mentioned]

Now, this text is full of Git jargon, in particular *tree-ish* and *pathspec*.  (Side note: *tree-ish* is defined in the Gitglossary, but I'm going to use a more pointed defintion here.)

The term *tree-ish* means: *I, Git, am fine here if you name a specific commit.  All I'm going to do with the commit is find its internal tree object, so you can give me that directly, if for some odd reason you really want to.  But really, just gimme something I can translate to a commit or tree, and I'll use the tree, or use the commit to find the tree.*

You provided `origin` here, and now it's time to go look at another piece of Git documentation.  (What, *another* one?  *Already?*)  [The gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_revisions) describes a six-step process for turning a name, like `master` or `develop` or `v2.1`, into a Git object hash ID.

The first step is to check whether there is a file in `.git` that has that name, and that step lets you use a name like `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` while you're in the middle of a conflicted `git cherry-pick`.  In this case, it doesn't apply.

The second step is to try the name as `refs/name`.  That second step lets you use `stash` or `stash@{number}` when you are using `git stash`.  In this case, it doesn't apply either.

The third step is to try the name as `refs/tags/name`.  That third step lets you use a name like `v2.1` to refer to the *tag* `v2.1`.  Since `origin` probably is not a valid tag name—you didn't tag any of your commits `origin`, did you?—this step is going to fail, so Git will move on to step #4.

The fourth step is to try the name as `refs/heads/name`.  This step allows you to use a branch name to specify a commit.  That's what lets you `git checkout master -- somefile`, for instance.  Since `master` *is* a valid branch name, `git checkout` will find the specific commit that `master` names—the tip of the `master` branch—and use that commit's tree—remember, we're executing the `git checkout <tree-ish> [--] <pathspec>...` syntax, and working on the `<tree-ish>` part here.

But you don't have a *branch* named `origin`, do you?  You might, if you created one!  I'd advise against creating one, but if you did, that's where this six-step process will stop.  Assuming you don't, though, the process goes on to step five.

Step five tries the name as `refs/remotes/name`.  You *will* have a *directory* named `refs/remotes/origin/` but that's not a valid ref so step five will fail, and the process will move to the last step.  If the last step fails, the whole thing fails, but...

Step six, the final one, tries the name as `refs/remotes/name/HEAD`.  Since `origin` is a valid remote, this *will* exist (well, unless you specifically deleted it, or in one other case that's not going to occur), and *will* be a valid commit specifier.  So step six succeeds: it finds that `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` exists and (probably) names `refs/remotes/origin/master`, which also exists, and *that* names a commit.

Thus, at this point the `<tree-ish>` part of the whole process is satisified: Git has translated `origin` to `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, or `origin/HEAD` for short; that's (probably) the same as `refs/remotes/origin/master`, or `origin/master` for short; and that's a valid commit, which would serve for either `git checkout` syntax rule #3 or for `git checkout` syntax rules #5 & #6.

Since we're working on the #5/#6 rules, we can go on and treat the *last* argument, `develop`, as a `<pathspec>`.  Now we have to look at yet another piece of Git documentation, namely [the Gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary).  We can jump straight to [the definition of a pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#gitglossary-aiddefpathspecapathspec), which is, unfortunately, very long and I'm not going to go through all of it here.

To sum up, though, a pathspec *can be*, and in this case *is*, just a file name.  So `develop` becomes a *file name*, and we have finished all the requirements for syntax rule(s) #5/#6.  Git will execute the action described in the yellow quoted text above, replacing the file `develop` in the index and work-tree, or simply erroring-out if the file `develop` does not exist by that name in the commit/`<tree-ish>` that we chose with the name `origin`.

Comment: By the way, `git checkout <tree-ish> [--] <pathspec>...` will be chattier with Git 2.21: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54281959/6309

Answer (score 1):

The command `git checkout origin develop` does not make much sense, because in Git only local branches are checked out.  Using `origin develop` refers to the `develop` branch on the remote.  You probably meant to do this:

```
git checkout develop
```

Assuming that there exists a remote tracking branch `origin/develop` (which is actually a local branch), the above would tell Git to create a new local branch called `develop`, which tracks the remote branch via the tracking branch `origin/develop`.